# How to change the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint in Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, navbar

I am using Meteor to build hybrid mobile app. I want the bootstrap navbar not to collapses on phones. According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), I should change the variable `@grid-float-breakpoint`, but I don't know how to do this in Meteor, since I can not even touch the bootstrap files in meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Still a bit green but you may want to do the following (assuming it isn't already done).

install less

```
meteor add less
```

clone a base set of stylesheets into you app/client/stylesheets directory

```
git clone https://github.com/DerMambo/stylesheets.git
```

vi into the custom.bootstrap.import.less file (app/client/stylesheets/vendor/)

find the @grid-float-breakpoint and set it to the value you need.

Hope this was helpful.